# Turning off auto layout seems to change the height of the screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

In order to make my app compatible for iOS 4.3, I need to untick the "Use Autolayout" option.

The problem is, once that is done, my interface objects don't show up where they need to be. The iOS simulator shows a screen with less height for some reason.

What should I do in order to keep the layout right, without using the auto layout option?

Comment: Do you mean that in the simulator the screen is that of an iPhone 4/4s/3/3gs and in the designer (Storyboard) the screen is that of an iPhone 5?

Comment: Unless you're stuck with an enterprise deployment on an old version of ios there's little reason to continue development for such an old version of the OS.

Comment: @uchuugaka Basically the project leader asked me to make sure it runs on the most possible devices. What version do you think I should make it for? Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @BlueGene I mean, I drop in buttons on the view in the interface builder, and when I run the simulator they do not show up at the same spot. The auto-layout used to fix this for me, but without it I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to set sizing and layout using IB

[image]

Comment: So, what I do is drop the items on the interface builder view as I want them to show up, and they do not show up like I've dropped them. Would using this tool solve it? I'm not sure how I would go about using this tool anyway! What about the different screen sizes?

Comment: Yes this would reposition controls if the screen size changes.  Not sure why you don't use AutoLayout though that is the recommended way, the alternative above is the old way.  Auto-layout is quite fiddly, one wrong constraint and the whole things falls apart, but it does work.

Comment: Alright, thanks i'll try it out! I don't use it because I want to make sure the app's compatible with the most possible iOS versions. Any iOS version below iOS 6 isn't compatible with autolayout.